# How to know the date of creation of an svn repository?

Tags: svn

I need to prove to my teacher that I created the svn repository before a certain date, but I do not know how to do it. If I type `svn info` inside the `local checked out folder` of the repository, I just obtain the `Last Changed Date`.

Comment: I guess this question has to be asked on StackOverflow or Superuser, not here.

Answer (score 1):

You may find repository creation date in svn:date revision property for revision 0. For example:

```
$ svn propget --revprop -r 0 svn:date http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
```

Will print:

```
2003-01-08T10:33:40.549533Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at:

```
svn log --quiet --stop-on-copy http://.../tags/...
```